# Can I point an Azure Pipelines build at TFS?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We're in the process of moving to Git, but currently our main codebase is on TFS.

We have a small project that needs its own build, but also needs to share a bunch of code that our main codebase uses.

Creating a new CloudBuild queue seems too heavy for this project, so we'd like to create its build in Azure Pipelines, but we're unsure if Pipeline builds support going to TFS.

Is this supported, and what's the best way to set it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Azure Pipelines take the code from your internal TFS server so no, is not supported. Azure Pipelines can take TFVC code only if the repository exist in Azure Repos.

Azure Pipelines can take external Git repository, so when you will move to Git you can build your code without any problem even is not stored in Azure Repos.